# is there is any reason that I cannot get my pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a blog to learn node and javascript and I have a problem. I cannot get my pages and I don't know why. Can someone lead me or give me an explanation to this problem, thanks.
I have put my index.js and my package.json below. As you can see I have installed nodemon and bootstrap and I'm doing all of these in cmd.

**index.js**

```
 const path = require('path');
 const expressEdge = require('express-edge');
 const express = require('express');

 const app = new express();

 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.use(expressEdge);
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './pages/index.html'));

 });

 app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './pages/about.html'));
 });

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/contact.html'));
 });

app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/post.html'));
 });

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 3000')
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "projet3web",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Create a blog",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},
 "keywords": [
  "blog"],
 "author": "Kym lusinchi Vincent Blanc El Hachemi Sabi",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
 "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
 "express": "^4.16.4",
 "express-edge": "^1.0.0",
 "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
 "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
 "startbootstrap-clean-blog": "file:startbootstrap-clean-blog",
 "tooltip.js": "^1.3.1"
 }
}
```

Comment: it seems i receive the error Cannot GET /index.html

Comment: Does it happen at the time when your page gets loaded or when you click on any link like `about`?

Comment: There is one more issue with your code, place generic route at the bottom.

Comment: it happens everytime i click on a link

Comment: Usually I use some view engine like pug or ejs but in this case you intend return a pure html right? 
I suggest you put console.log(path.resolve(...)) before call res.sendFile to make sure html path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

check if your route in the res.send is correct. i dont think you need the .html

i dont know how your files tree looks like but if it is standart you wont need the dot in the beggining of the path

anyway i think you should use res.render('/');

Comment: i have a file call pages for every link, it contains for example contact.html

Answer (score 0):

When you do `app.use(express.static('public'))`, you're serving all files under `public` folder as `static` files.

Assuming (from your code) your folder structure is

```
.
+-- index.js
+-- public
|   +-- pages
|   |   +-- index.html
|   |   +-- about.html
|   |   ...
```

The files in your `pages` folder can be accessed like: `localhost:3000/pages/index.html`

Also, you've not defined a path `/index.html`, express is rendering the error.